Monkeypatching pandas series to_csv with pytest
I am testing a function, write_query(), in module.py.  My test is in test_module.py, which is carried out using pytest.  I am using the pytest monkeypatch fixture to monkeypatch Series.to_csv(), in order to prevent file writing.  It works in part - my monkeypatched function performs checks that seem to complete, and raises an error that is expected and indicates a passed test (I did this so I could explicitly include a test in the test function, rather than calling the function in a test and have the test performed in the function alone).  However, it is still writing a file, doesnt_matter, and I'm not sure why.  Can anyone explain?
Thanks!
Tim
folder/module.py
import pandas as pd

def write_query(df, outpath, entry_name_col):
    
    #Make a list of queries.  NB - no pandas objects/methods involved in 
    #build_query()
    entry_names = build_query(df, entry_name_col) 
    
    #Write the queries to a csv
    with open(outpath, 'w') as csv_file: 
        pd.Series(entry_names).to_csv(csv_file,
                                      index=False, 
                                      lineterminator='\n', 
                                      header = False)

folder/test_module.py
import os
import pytest
from folder.module import build_query, write_query

def temp_to_csv(self, csv_file, index, lineterminator, header):

    #check csv_file is correct
    assert csv_file.name == 'doesnt_matter'

    #check values to be written are correct
    if list(self.values) == ['(id:"entry_name_1")', '(id:"entry_name_2")']:

        #if they are, raise an error with a specific message that can be checked 
        #in the main test.  
        raise ValueError('Correct values passed to to_csv') 

    else: 
        raise ValueError
        
class TestWriteQuery:
    def test_normal(self, 
                    good_input_queries,   #dataframe fixture in conftest.py 
                    monkeypatch):

        #check file doesnt exist before function is called
        assert 'doesnt_matter' not in os.listdir(os.getcwd())  #This passes
        
        #monkeypatch Series.to_csv() - have also tried module.pd.Series.to_csv, 
        #pandas.Series.to_csv, pd.Series.to_csv, Series.to_csv
        monkeypatch.setattr('folder.module.pd.Series.to_csv', 
                            temp_to_csv)

        #call function and test raised error
        with pytest.raises(ValueError) as e:                   #This passes
            write_query(good_input_queries, 
                        outpath = 'doesnt_matter', 
                        entry_name_col = 'Entry name')
        #e is <ExceptionInfo ValueError('Correct values passed to to_csv') tblen=3>
        assert 'Correct values passed to to_csv' in str(e)     #This passes
        
        #check file has not been written
        assert 'doesnt_matter' not in os.listdir(os.getcwd())  #This fails


unless you have a setattr static method on your object I'm pretty sure monkey patching should be done via i.e. (assuming your object is mutable):
obj.setattr("new",6)
or
obj.new=6

Hello, thanks for your reply - my post was unclear and I have edited it.  I am using the pytest monkeypatch fixture to perform the monkeypatching, which is what I am having issues with (rather than monkeypatching in terms of the broader technique).
